# Is there an alternative to ISession.Merge() that doesn't throw when using optimistic locking?

Tags: nhibernate, merge, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

I've been trying to use ISession.Merge() to keep coherence between two sessions, but it fails when the merged instance has a higher Version property than the one loaded in the session (with a StaleObjectStateException).

Is there an alternative method that would work when the Version fields do not match ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to safely merge entities between sessions, at least with optimistic-locking.

I'm going with another pattern: each session has its own copies of each entity, and I `refresh()` the instances on each session as needed. This has added overhead in memory usage and round-trips to the DB, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
Session.Lock(string entityName, object obj, LockMode lockMode);
```

with LockMode.Force. The remarks for that method state:

> This may be used to perform a version check
>   (NHibernate.LockMode.Read), to upgrade to a pessimistic lock
>   (NHibernate.LockMode.Upgrade), or to simply reassociate a transient
>   instance with a session (NHibernate.LockMode.None). This operation
>   cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with
>   cascade="lock".

And for LockMode.Force:

> Similar to NHibernate.LockMode.Upgrade except that, for versioned
>   entities, it results in a forced version increment.

Comment: The documentation and litterature elsewere make me think that LockMode.Force will rather force a write of a new Version to the DB, rather than get the latest state...I'll see what I can do with it though.

Comment: Confirmed, LockMode.Force forces NHibernate to send a SQL update, which is the opposite of what I want here.